# php for loop: error message if condition not met

Tags: php, for-loop

My foreach loop:

```
$empty = "You cannot decommission this truck. It is in use."
$msg = "";
foreach ($trucks_to_remove as $truck_id) {
    $truck_id = trim($truck_id);
    if (strlen($truck_id)) {
        $msg .= decom_truck(
            $db,
            $depot_id,
            $truck_id
        );
        }
    else
    {
    echo $empty;
    }
}
echo $msg;
```

If the condition is not met, it means the sql cursor that preceded this foreach loop did not return a result for this truck_id (meaning it is in use), I just want a simple message sent to the page to alert the user.

It does not have to be a pop-up or the like.  Where would I put my write or print statement? I assume I'd use an else clause but when I add an else inside the foreach loop (see above), I get nothing printed to the page. I have also tried the following:

```
   else if (strlen($truck_id)) == 0
    {
    echo $empty;
    }
```

I am very new to php.

Comment: if (strlen($truck_id)) should be if (strlen($truck_id)>0)

Comment: @SpiderLinked They're equivalent, since `0` is falsy and any other number is truthy.

Comment: have you checked if control is transferred to the else statement ever

Comment: @Barmar you are right...didn't thought like that....

Comment: What does `var_dump($trucks_to_remove)` show? If the array is empty, the entire loop will be skipped and nothing will be printed.

Comment: The array is empty.  Is there a way to print the message if it is empty?

Comment: you are missing a semicolon at the end of $empty variable

Comment: That is true. I added the semi-colon but that did not produce different results.

Comment: i ran the code and it works as you intend, dosn't seems any problem

Comment: @Barmar When I add the var dump statement, nothing is printed to the page as well. Bsienn - is that what you mean by show?

Comment: yes, so basically array is empty so no loop runs, hence no if statement, what else you are looking for? the array is empty the loop won't run

Comment: I am looking for a message to be displayed in case the array is empty.

Comment: Nothing is displayed? If the array is empty, it should display `Array(0)`.

Comment: if nothing is displayed by `var_dump`, your problem is that somewhere other than the code you posted. Nothing being displayed by this page is being rendered. Is this an AJAX function or a regular web page?

Comment: It must be elsewhere since I have tried what @Bsienn recommended.  I need to do further research so I can edit this question.  I will update as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr1 = array();
if(!$arr1)
{
    echo 'arr1 is emty<br/>';

    $arr2 = array(1, 2);
    if($arr2)
        echo 'arr2 has data';

    exit();
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me when I use "trucks_to_remove" as the array so I need to do further research to see what else this could be and then modify my question.

Comment: As Barman asked, is this a simple page or you are calling i through ajax. can you post your script at http://pastebin.com/ so i can see where is problem. also put var_dump result of your array